# Why does flash work on Google Chrome?

Tags: debian

So I installed Debian Wheezy and Google Chrome and found Youtube and other flash sites working. Typically in Linux environments, the user will need to go around installing plugins to get this working. Any ideas on what the technical implementation is of this stack that results in the user not having to install anything manually?

Comment: I believe the question is based on a wrong assumption - does *Flash* really work there? It's simply that youtube and a bunch of other sites have also non-Flash video players that are used depending on what browser/OS is detected, so the site is not a "Flash site" anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Adobe Flash Player is directly integrated with Google Chrome and enabled by default. Available updates for Adobe Flash Player are automatically included in Chrome system updates.

More info here...

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/108086?hl=en

Comment: PDF reader too!  I'm sure there are more.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can think of a few possibilities:

1. More and more websites (including YouTube) are using HTML5 players instead of Flash ones (because Apple device doesn't support it)
2. Chrome Sync can sync apps, auto-fill information, bookmarks, extensions, omni-box history, password, settings, themes, and open tabs. This can save people time tweaking settings or searching for information - so if You connected Your Chrome to Your Google account, it's possible that it installed a few extensions by itself